How to make only one column to trigger sorting?
So I'm building a table with Tanstack Table library. I need only the "Age" column to sort when it's clicked. How do i do it?
<thead>
    {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th
                  key={header.id}
                  onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}
                >
                  {header.isPlaceholder ? null : (
                    <div>
                      {flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.header,
                        header.getContext()
                      )}
                      {
                        header.column.getIsSorted() === "asc"
                          ? ""
                          : header.column.getIsSorted() === "desc"
                          ? ""
                          : null
                      }
                    </div>
                  )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
</thead>

Right know all of the columns are able to be sorted when clicked. I've tried this method, but it didn't work: {header.column.name === 'Age' && onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()} }

Have you tried onClick={header.column.name === 'Age' && header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}?

Try adding enableSorting in column array. Check this https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/guide/sorting#disable-sorting
